# Change rule of validation in woocommerce

Tags: regex, wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I need to change validation of poscode field in checkout process. Its declarated in class-wc-validation. It must be a format "AZ 12" ( letter letter space number number).

Comment: So, whats stopping you? Go ahead and validate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own validate function. Paste the following code in your theme's functions.php.

```
apply_filters('woocommerce_validate_postcode','your_validate_f');

function your_validate_f($valid, $postcode, $country){
  // check your $postcode, if valid $valid=true else false
  return $valid;
}
```